# threesixty sliderが表示されない

Tags: jquery

http://360slider.com/よりthreesixty sliderをダウンロードして
下記テスト環境にを設置したのですが動きません。
http://rapport-net.com/360/

どうしたらよいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

jQuery3.0を使用しているのが原因と思われます。
3.0ではいくつかのメソッドが廃止されましたが、threesixty-sliderが使用している`.load()`メソッドもその1つです。
jQueryのバージョンを2系に下げて試してみてください。

Comment: cither様
解決できました!
ありがとうございます！

Comment: 解決したなら、解決済みのチェックを付けてください